# WCF Service Call - Only Partial Parameters On Timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service and I'm experiencing a strange issue.

One of our vendors is calling one of our methods and claims to be sending us 3 good parameters.  The first thing the method does is log the value of all incoming parameters to our database.  When I look at the logged message, I am seeing only 2 of the parameters populated.  The vendor claims that this is because the method is timing out before the third parameter is sent.  I was under the impression that if the method timed out we would see an exception, not a full execution of the web method with some missing parameters.

Is the vendor right?  Are we timing out and just executing the method with the parameters that have made it so far?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a network monitoring tool (aka sniffer) to check what is sent by your vendor. You'll have a proof of what he sent to your service. A timeout may discard/corrupt the message but will hardly generate a readable message with missing values. Make sure you are not using a Streamed transport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is message based, that means that the entire message is created and sent, you wouldn't get a partial list of parameters, in other words the parameters would be fully materialized BEFORE your service method has been invoked.  Answering questions with no code is rather difficult to fully understand, but your vendor clearly doesn't understand how WCF works if they think parameters are "timing out".

You would be better served by adding some logging, for example:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Critical, Error, Verbose, Warning, Information,  ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="sdt"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Add this to your web/config on the WCF service side to see any error as well as WCF activity.  But it doesn't sound like you are getting an error, it sounds like you are not getting passed a parameter.